Uncomfortable with the definition of measure zero in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds
In Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, page 91 Definition (of measure zero) it states: Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. We say $A$ has measure zero in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a covering $Q_{1},Q_{2},\cdots$ of $A$ by countably many rectangle such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v(Q_{i})<\epsilon$.
In Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, page 29 it states: For example, suppose $Q$ is the rectangle
$$Q=[a_{1},b_{1}]\times\cdots\times[a_{n},b_{n}],$$
consisting of all points $\mathbf{x}$ of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ such that $a_{i}<x_{i}<b_{i}$ for all $i$.
In a long time, I haven't realized, in the definition of measure zero, the edges of these $Q_{1},Q_{2},\cdots$ are paralleled with coordinate axes in Munkres' context. Without this realization, measure zero still work “normally” in most situations. Here are my questions.
(i) Are edges of these $Q_{1},Q_{2},\cdots$ mentioned in “Definition of measure zero” paralleled with coordinate axes?
(ii) If the answer of (i) is “yes”, I feel uncomfortable with this “Definition of measure zero”. I think, to define measure zero, it is not necessary that the edges of these $Q_{1},Q_{2},\cdots$ must be paralleled with coordinate axes. And removing this parallelism restriction will make the definition of measure zero more natural. How to overcome these uncomfortable feelings?


Are edges of these $Q_{1},Q_{2},\cdots$ mentioned in “Definition of measure zero” paralleled with coordinate axes?

Yes. A rectangle in this context is a Cartesian product of closed intervals (a "box" if you will); hence the coordinate axes are necessarily parallel to the edges.

If the answer of (i) is “yes”, I feel uncomfortable with this “Definition of measure zero”. I think, to define measure zero, it is not necessary that the edges of these $Q_{1},Q_{2},\cdots$ must be paralleled with coordinate axes. And removing this parallelism restriction will make the definition of measure zero more natural. How to overcome these uncomfortable feelings?

Perhaps the restriction can be lifted, but generally there is no need for one to.
The reason why we often use rectangles (boxes, intervals, whatever) in these cases is because they're very, very simplistic objects with a very, very natural notion for what their measure should be (their hypervolume, $\prod_i (b_i-a_i)$).
If you wish to insist that, more generally, you be allowed to use a higher-dimensional variant of a parallelipiped - to keep the "boxiness" (for lack of a better word) of these "rectangles" but without having the parallelism - this is entirely fine in principle.
The reason is that, ultimately, you can construct an invertible linear transformation $T$ that takes such an $n$-parallelipiped to a "rectangle" and back again (up to some trivial considerations, e.g. handling translations). There is also a more general result: if $E$ is measurable, and $T$ is a linear transformation (or even just Lipschitz-continuous) then $T(E)$ is measurable with
$$
\mu(T(E)) = |\det(T)| \cdot \mu(E)
$$
wherein we assume $0\cdot \infty$ to be $0$, and $\mu$ being the Lebesgue measure here (I'm not sure offhand if it holds more generally).
However, outside of very specialized examples, I don't think you'll find this allowance to help you too much, since the measure of a general parallelipiped would be a bit too complicated to work with most of the time.
